# List of AzureDevOps users --> Who added the users to AzureDevOps Organization

Tags: azure-devops

Need help on to find out Who added the users to Azure DevOps Organizations and who Provided the licensing (Basic or Basic+Testplan) to the users.

can some help how to find it?

I'm able to get the list of Azure DevOps users and Licensing what they have. But not able to find who added them to Organization and Who provided Basic licensing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add users to Azure DevOps organization, you must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators or Project Administrators group for the organization that you want to invite external users to. Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=azure-devops).

For DevOps organization backed to an Azure Active Directory, you could check the auditing log in Organization Settings -> Auditing

[image]

Here is the [Auditing events list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/audit/auditing-events?view=azure-devops#areas) available in Azure DevOps.

Comment: Thanks Kim for support.  I can see only two days data , Is there any way to more data.

Comment: The Audit Events should get stored for 90 days, after which they're deleted. If you have just enabled this feature for your DevOps organization, then there will be limited data to read. If not, try using the Filter button to filter your target date.